# Extracting multiple Data types from "messy" Java String

Tags: java, string, list, text, extract

I need to extract the name, year, and rating from a text file as a String, Int, and float respectively. I am then instantiating a list of objects with the data I pull out. I have buffered out a single string of text that looks like this.

```
!Women Art Revolution (2010) |   3 stars, 1hr 22m
```

I then split this string into two parts at the "|" character.

```
String[] splitStr  = line.split("|");
                part1 = splitStr[0];
                part2 = splitStr[1];
```

I plan to use a scanner and collect all the Int's from part1 into a string and grab the last four to use for the year.  I am going to use a similar method for the rating. My problem has been getting the name string. Scanner.next doesn't seem to grab symbols like !, numbers, and () from the title names. The title names from the full text file are not in any particular format that seems easy to parse out. How would I create a String for the titles to use in my constructor?

```
masterList.add(new Movie(name, year, rating));
```

Also, example from some of the larger list(totaling 10k or so items):

```
3-Day Weekend (2008) |   2.9 stars, 1hr 23m
3:15 (U.S) (1986) |   2.9 stars, 53m
Real (2011) |   3.7 stars, 1hr 34m
Real: The Movie (2005) |   3.3 stars, 1hr 31m
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use regex?

For example, the regex `^!(.*) \((\d*)\) *\| *([\d.]*) *stars,.*$` will give you the name, year and rating in capturing group 1,2 and 3 respectively.

---

Update: Extra references

1. For the syntax of regex (regular expression) itself supported in Java, you can refer to [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
2. You may find a introductory [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) of Regex in Java

Here is the explanation of the regex itself, by breaking down into small pieces:

- `^`: starting with
- `!`: an exclamation mark
- `(`: start of capturing group 1
- `.*`: any number of occurrence of any character
- `)`: end of capturing group 1
- `\(`: an open parenthesis
- `(`:start of capturing group 2
- `\d*`: any number of occurrence of digits
- `)`: end of capturing group 2
- `\)`: a close parenthesis
- `*`: any number of white spaces
- `\|` : a pipe character
- `*`: any number of white spaces
- `(` : start of capturing group 3
- `[\d.]*`: any no of occurrence of digits or dot
- `)`: end of capturing group 3
- `*`: any number of white spaces
- `stars,` : follow by the string `stars,`
- `.*`: follow by any number of occurrence of any characters
- `$`: till the end of string

Sample code:

```
String input = "!Women Art Revolution (2010) |   3 stars, 1hr 22m";

// mind the extra escaping of \ char because of Java string literal escaping
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^!(.*) \\((\\d*)\\) *\\| *([\\d.]*) *stars,.*$");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
System.out.println("matches? " + m.matches());
System.out.println("name: " + m.group(1));
System.out.println("name: " + m.group(2));
System.out.println("name: " + m.group(3));
```

It should give you

```
matches? true
name: Women Art Revolution
name: 2010
name: 3
```

Comment: I am newer to java and haven't heard of regex. Could you elaborate on the syntax?

Comment: Have adjust a bit on the regex itself to cope with your updated pattern (due to possible dot in rating)

Comment: Okay, thanks so much. Sorry for not being clear from the onset. Regex seems super useful, I'm embarrassed I haven't learned it. Also I'm assuming group() returns Strings?

Comment: @user2430428 go ahead and check the API of Matcher.  (You should start learning how to make use of API document)